# How to bring in new users when the site is public?

Tags: discussion, target-audience

The Japanese SE's public beta will begin on June 7th at 1900 UTC.

How will you be hyping up the site to your friends, family, and colleagues?

What can we do to convince someone that this site is worth their time when compared to some other Japanese language discussion forum? There's no need for them to stop going to whichever one(s) they already use (that would be too forceful and we don't want to be or appear to be confrontational), but we would certainly like to convince them that it's worth their time to also spend some cycles browsing and contributing to the Japanese SE site.

Not everyone may be familiar with how an SE site works, so how will you be explaining it to other people?

Answer (score 1):

I think this really comes down to the content. If there is content that organically draws in new users, then the site will continue to grow. It might even be worthwhile to find out what types of questions people are searching the web for, then make sure that there are question/answers on this site that cover those topics.

We can also make sure to share our favorite questions on Facebook/Twitter in order to expose our peers to the site.